# Maximum flow on a n ×n grid

Tags: graphs, square-grid

I am currently dealing with a network flow problem and I am trying to find some similar solved problems to help me formulate my solution.

The text is:

You are the owner of a large chain of franchise shops, and you would like to expand to a new city. The blocks in your
city make an $n ×n$ grid. However, although your products are awesome and in high demand, the city will not allow
you to open a shop in each block. Instead, for every row of blocks i, you are are given a number $r_i$ that limits the
maximum number of shops opened there - and for every column j, there also is a maximum number $c_j$ .

a) Find the maximum number of franchise shops you can legally open in the city. To do so, model the problem as a
flow network. Then, describe how to get the right answer using Ford-Fulkerson, and prove the correctness of your
construction.

How can I construct the digraph from the $n ×n$ grid ?
I think the blocks can be represented in this way
[grid](https://media.cheggcdn.com/media%2F2b2%2F2b2dcde8-fb91-41eb-a5b3-d01d990d0867%2FphpUTTqWb.png)
Should I assume an initial orientation on the grid?

> Image taken by https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/n-x-n-grid-graphs-defined-drawing-nx-n-grid-vertices-connecting-adjacent-vertices-drawn-g3-q30726135

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 2):

Assume an $n\times n$ grid.  I'd build a network as follows.  A source on the left with $n$ arcs going to $n$ nodes each representing a row of the grid.  Call these $n$ nodes $R_1, R_2...R_n$.  The flow capacity on the $i^{th}$ arc (from source to $R_i$) is $r_i$.  Do something similar at the sink.  Have arcs arriving there from nodes $C_1,C_2..C_n$ with capacity $c_i$.  Then connect each $R_i$ to $C_j$ with an arc of capacity 1.  Maximize the flow.  The arcs $R_i-C_j$ chosen to have a flow in an optimal solution will tell you to place a franchise at grid point $i,j$.

Comment: But in this way the minimum capacity along a path is always 1 and the flow is the same for every paths, am I wrong?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well there are $n^2$ paths.  That is, every node of the grid corresponds to a path.  So you can only pick them all if your $r_i$ and $c_i$ are at least $n$.  But for the general case, the flows will be maximal subject to those constraints and will pick out the max number of grid points that are feasible.

Comment: Is this correct for 3x3 ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RIRf6xiK9o0u8Y3tVdKaa1kwyKuqNSUv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Assuming a full 3x3 grid, you're missing 6 arcs in the middle ($R_1$ to $C_2$, $R_1$ to $C_3$, $R_2$ to $C_1$.......)  So each point of the grid (say in row $i$ and column $j$) corresponds to an arc from $R_i$ to $C_j$.

Comment: Ok thank you but I don't get the capacity of 1. For example: in the path S-->$R_1$-->$C_1$-->T the minimum capacity is 1 so for every arcs flows exactly 1 (1/$r_1$,1,1/$c_1$) and so on for the others.

Comment: What do you mean "minimum" capacity?  I assume 0 flow is feasible on any arc (i.e. there is no arc that HAS to have flow on it).

Comment: I mean the "bottleneck". But to reach T I need to pass through $R_1$ - $C_1$

Comment: Say $r_3=1$ then you can only have one unit of flow on $S$-->$R_3$.  That unit of flow goes to some $C_k$ then to $T$ (assuming $c_k>0$).  So there can't be a second flow that leaves $R_3$ because you've used up the capacity into $R_3$.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, you're right but I mean another thing: Since the capacity between $R_i$ and $C_j$ is 1 in a path from S to T can only flows 1 even if $r_i > 1$ and $c_j > 1$

Comment: Two points: (1) if you can assign more than one franchise to a given grid point (I doubt  it) then you can increase the $R_i$-->$C_j$ capacity to some max number of franchises to place in one grid point.  (2) If $r_i>1$ then yes one unit will be used by $R_i$-->$C_j$ but other flows can use units of row $i$'s capacity too e.g. maybe $R_i$-->$C_k$ (for $k<>j$).  Similarly for column capacity.

Comment: ah ok, now I got it. thank you very much for your time.